# sort Y according to sorted X

Tags: matlab, sorting, classification

```
X = [2.3 4.1 1.9 5.8 6.7 7.5 9.3 15.0 1.6 3.1]

Y = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
```

length of both vectors is equal.

I want to sort X by value, but then sort Y according to the same rearrangement that sort did to X.

What's the easiest way to do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[B I]=sort(X);
% I is the index
Y=Y(I);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sortrows()` function in matlab is also a good solution.

```
XY = [X' Y'];
XY = sortrows(XY,1);% sort both columns in ascending order of X values or col-1
X = (XY(:,1))';
Y = (XY(:,2))';
```